# UrlUnescape() and unicode chars

Tags: windows, winapi, url, unicode

I am trying to write the program on C++ that will decode the URL-encoded string that contains some URL-encoded unicode characters.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring test = L"bla+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%84+%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E";
    PWSTR urlencodedStr = const_cast<WCHAR*>(test.c_str());
    WCHAR decodedStr[1025];
    DWORD size = 1024;
    HRESULT hres = UrlUnescape(urlencodedStr, decodedStr, &size, NULL);

    if (hres == S_OK)
        MessageBox(NULL, decodedStr, L"decoded string", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to get L"bla блоф 日本語" in **decodedStr**. But i'm getting L"bla+Ð±Ð»Ð¾Ñ„+æ—¥æœ¬èªž" instead.
I am using unicode charset in my build.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So i wrote my own function to decode URL-encoded strings with unicode characters. Here it is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <wininet.h> // For INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

bool IsHexChar(const WCHAR _char)
{
    return ((_char == L'A') || 
            (_char == L'B') ||
            (_char == L'C') ||
            (_char == L'D') ||
            (_char == L'E') ||
            (_char == L'F') || 
            iswalnum(_char));
}

std::wstring UrlDecode(const std::wstring& _encodedStr)
{
    std::string charStr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < _encodedStr.length(); ++i)
    {
        if ((_encodedStr[i] == L'%') && (IsHexChar(_encodedStr[i+1])) && (IsHexChar(_encodedStr[i+2])))
        {
            std::wstring hexCodeStr = L"0x";
            hexCodeStr += _encodedStr[i+1];
            hexCodeStr += _encodedStr[i+2];

            unsigned int hexCharCode;   
            std::wstringstream ss;
            ss << std::hex << hexCodeStr;
            ss >> hexCharCode;

            charStr += static_cast<char>(hexCharCode);

            i += 2;
        }
        else if (_encodedStr[i] == L'+')
            charStr += L' ';
        else
            charStr += _encodedStr[i];
    }

    WCHAR decodedStr[INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, charStr.c_str(), -1, decodedStr, sizeof(decodedStr));

    return decodedStr;
}
```

Use like this:

```
std::wstring encodedStr = L"bla+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%84+%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E";
std::wstring decodedStr = UrlDecode(encodedStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`UrlUnescape` converts URL-decoded `%xx` bytes into characters using the default (ANSI) code page by default. This is almost never what you want.

From Windows 8 onwards, you can pass the [UNESCAPE_AS_UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#url_unescape_as_utf8) flag to make it behave. If you can't depend on Win8, you'll have to use/write a different URL-decoding library call that doesn't suffer from this problem.

Also there is the issue of the `+`: in plain-URL-encoding (for example for use in a path part), this means a plus, but in form-url-encoding (for example in a query parameter), which is what you seem to have here, it means a space. A good URL decoder will give you the option to say which one you mean; `UrlUnescape` does not. An alternative is to manually replace the `+` with space on input before URL-decoding; this is one special case and no other characters are similarly affected.